# Check how many processor cores my Python code is running on?

Tags: python, process, top, htop

I want to check how many cores my Python script is using.
Suppose that I have this code:

```
while True:
    print('Hello World!')
```

When I run `top`, it gives the CPU, Memory, percentage in addition to other information but not the cores id or how many cores the process is using.

```
top - 11:44:15 up 1 day, 23:08,  1 user,  load average: 2.88, 2.39, 2.15
Tasks: 289 total,   5 running, 238 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 55.2 us, 31.8 sy,  0.0 ni, 12.8 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.2 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem :  7945496 total,  1027328 free,  4707680 used,  2210488 buff/cache
KiB Swap: 15999996 total, 14991876 free,  1008120 used.  2615420 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                                 
15336 lenovo    20   0 4393044 470488 192616 S   8.6  5.9 148:18.31 firefox                                                                                                                                 
 4412 lenovo    20   0 4521092 437940  65416 R  15.6  5.5  87:58.54 gnome-shell                                                                                                                             
 4221 root      20   0  561840  82500  45652 R   9.9  1.0  84:25.21 Xorg                                                                                                                                    
15395 lenovo    20   0 3871472 319376 151876 S   0.0  4.0  83:57.26 Web Content                                                                                                                             
 2838 lenovo    20   0 3993616 823816 158412 R  68.5 10.4  36:28.10 Web Content                                                                                                                             
 4435 lenovo     9 -11 2915368  11596   8836 S   0.3  0.1  35:46.08 pulseaudio                                                                                                                              
 3342 lenovo    20   0 3060860 324000 127948 S   8.6  4.1  27:53.92 atom                                                                                                                                    
29632 lenovo    20   0 3717204 750864 152688 S  10.3  9.5  22:25.05 Web Content                                                                                                                             
15443 lenovo    20   0 3273020 245772  50128 S   2.3  3.1  19:49.64 WebExtensions                                                                                                                           
 3293 lenovo    20   0 1291576 215972 112612 S   4.6  2.7  15:38.90 atom                                                                                                                                    
 3319 lenovo    20   0  734208 226016 104340 S   5.6  2.8  14:52.60 atom                                                                                                                                    
 1446 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   1.0  0.0  14:21.71 irq/132-nvidia                                                                                                                          
16083 lenovo    20   0  446420  35468  27844 S   1.3  0.4  11:06.27 RDD Process                                                                                                                             
29733 lenovo    20   0 3537988 363160 235184 S   0.0  4.6   9:29.13 Web Content                                                                                                                             
29780 lenovo    20   0 3414220 363812 174640 S   0.3  4.6   7:50.64 Web Content                                                                                                                             
29570 lenovo    20   0 3068760 245412 125788 S   0.3  3.1   4:14.76 Web Content                                                                                                                             
 1733 gdm       20   0 3464584  75712  45704 S   0.0  1.0   4:08.74 gnome-shell
```

I did some googling, and I found this command:

```
watch -tdn0.5 ps -mo pid,tid,%cpu,psr -p \`pgrep python\`
```

Which outputs:

```
  PID   TID %CPU PSR
15329     - 95.2   -
    - 15329 95.2   1
```

Well I am not sure if the previous command really does the trick or not.
If anyone could give an explanation, I would be grateful.

**EDIT:**
I am using Ubuntu 18.04 the desktop version.
Kernel version :

```
4.15.0-99-generic #100-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 22 20:32:56 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `top`, you can show the "last used CPU":

```
Fields Management for window 1:Def, whose current sort field is %CPU
   Navigate with Up/Dn, Right selects for move then <Enter> or Left commits,
   'd' or <Space> toggles display, 's' sets sort.  Use 'q' or <Esc> to end!

* PID     = Process Id             SUSER   = Saved User Name        vMj     = Major Faults delta  
  PPID    = Parent Process pid     GID     = Group Id               vMn     = Minor Faults delta  
  TGID    = Thread Group Id        GROUP   = Group Name             USED    = Res+Swap Size (KiB) 
* USER    = Effective User Name    PGRP    = Process Group Id       nsIPC   = IPC namespace Inode 
* PR      = Priority               TTY     = Controlling Tty        nsMNT   = MNT namespace Inode 
* NI      = Nice Value             TPGID   = Tty Process Grp Id     nsNET   = NET namespace Inode 
* VIRT    = Virtual Image (KiB)    SID     = Session Id             nsPID   = PID namespace Inode 
* RES     = Resident Size (KiB)    TIME    = CPU Time               nsUSER  = USER namespace Inode
  SHR     = Shared Memory (KiB)    SWAP    = Swapped Size (KiB)     nsUTS   = UTS namespace Inode 
* %CPU    = CPU Usage              CODE    = Code Size (KiB)        LXC     = LXC container name  
* %MEM    = Memory Usage (RES)     DATA    = Data+Stack (KiB)       RSan    = RES Anonymous (KiB) 
* TIME+   = CPU Time, hundredths   nMaj    = Major Page Faults      RSfd    = RES File-based (KiB)
  nTH     = Number of Threads      nMin    = Minor Page Faults      RSlk    = RES Locked (KiB)    
  P       = Last Used Cpu (SMP)    nDRT    = Dirty Pages Count      RSsh    = RES Shared (KiB)    
* S       = Process Status         Flags   = Task Flags <sched.h>   CGNAME  = Control Group name  
  WCHAN   = Sleeping in Function   CGROUPS = Control Groups         NU      = Last Used NUMA node 
* COMMAND = Command Name/Line      SUPGIDS = Supp Groups IDs     
  UID     = Effective User Id      SUPGRPS = Supp Groups Names   
  RUID    = Real User Id           OOMa    = OOMEM Adjustment    
  RUSER   = Real User Name         OOMs    = OOMEM Score current 
  SUID    = Saved User Id          ENVIRON = Environment vars
```

Press `f`, navigate to `P` (Last Used CPU), press `d` to mark it for display, and press `q` to go back to the process view.

To show the threads instead of processes (a process runs on multiple CPUs at once by having its threads scheduled on them), run `top` with the `-H` option, or press `H` after starting it.

Example with Firefox:

```
top - 03:25:57 up  2:36,  1 user,  load average: 0.61, 0.43, 0.45
Threads:  86 total,   0 running,  86 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):   2.4/1.2     4[|||                                                                                                 ]
GiB Mem : 23.7/15.4     [                                                                                                    ]
GiB Swap:  0.0/0.0      [                                                                                                    ]

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+  P S COMMAND                                                                                                                                                                   
   3870 muru      20   0 3354.0m 461.1m   2.0   2.9  13:43.39  4 S firefox                                                                                                                                                                   
   3875 muru      20   0 3354.0m 461.1m   0.7   2.9   2:54.10  0 S Gecko_IOThread                                                                                                                                                            
   4063 muru      20   0 3354.0m 461.1m   0.7   2.9   0:12.78  9 S URL Classifier                                                                                                                                                            
   3873 muru      20   0 3354.0m 461.1m   0.0   2.9   0:00.00  6 S gmain                                                                                                                                                                     
   3874 muru      20   0 3354.0m 461.1m   0.0   2.9   0:08.25  6 S gdbus                                                                                                                                                                     
   3876 muru      20   0 3354.0m 461.1m   0.0   2.9   0:31.17  1 S Timer                                                                                                                                                                     
   3877 muru      20   0 3354.0m 461.1m   0.0   2.9   0:00.00  8 S Netlink Monitor                                                                                                                                                           
   3878 muru      20   0 3354.0m 461.1m   0.0   2.9   0:16.99  9 S Socket Thread                                                                                                                                                             
   3879 muru      20   0 3354.0m 461.1m   0.0   2.9   0:00.43 11 S Permission                                                                                                                                                                
   3882 muru      20   0 3354.0m 461.1m   0.0   2.9   0:00.25  6 S JS Watchdog                                                                                                                                                               
   3883 muru      20   0 3354.0m 461.1m   0.0   2.9   0:02.15 11 S JS Helper
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a great tool, similar to `top`, but with more details.
[htop](https://hisham.hm/htop/), it can be installed by running `sudo apt install htop`.

This is the default interface after running `htop`.

[image]

As you can see, there are much more information about the running processes, CPU and memory usage.
Similar to `top`, it is also possible to add new columns with more information.
In my case, to display on which core the process/thread is running:

1. Press <kbd>F2</kbd> (or <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> for some computers).
2. Move down to **columns** section under **Setup**.
3. Press the right arrow key to move to **Active Columns**, you can move up or down to choose the place where to add the new column.
4. Press the right arrow key to move to the **Available Columns**.
5. Move to the column you want to add and press enter once it is selected.
6. Once the new column added, press <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

Here is a screenshot after I added the new column:

[image]

Comment: Note that most of what you see here can be shown in `top` too (try pressing `1` and `c`).

Comment: @muru, you're right, I've checked `man top` and I discovered a lot of tricks that can be done with top